# Iteration to make OrderedDict

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration, ordereddictionary

I'm working on iterating through to make an Ordered Dict for a bar chart.

In my working code for the year I get the months for the bar chart this way:

```
Jan = pivot_table[1].astype(float).values
Feb = pivot_table[2].astype(float).values
Mar = pivot_table[3].astype(float).values
Apr = pivot_table[4].astype(float).values
May = pivot_table[5].astype(float).values
Jun = pivot_table[6].astype(float).values
Jul = pivot_table[7].astype(float).values
Aug = pivot_table[8].astype(float).values
Sep = pivot_table[9].astype(float).values
Oct = pivot_table[10].astype(float).values
Nov = pivot_table[11].astype(float).values
Dec = pivot_table[12].astype(float).values
```

Then I write the months into an `OrderedDict`

```
months = OrderedDict([('Jan', Jan), ('Feb', Feb), ('Mar', Mar), ('Apr',Apr), ('May',May), ('Jun',Jun),('Jul',Jul), ('Aug',Aug), ('Sep',Sep),('Oct',Oct),('Nov',Nov),('Dec',Dec)])
```

Obviously this is not ideal. Therefore, I wrote a loop instead.

```
months=[]
for month in range(1, 13):
    months.append(pivot_table[str(month)].astype(float).values)

months = OrderedDict([('Jan', 1), ('Feb', 2), ('Mar', 3), ('Apr',4), ('May',5), ('Jun',6),('Jul',7), ('Aug',8), ('Sep',9),('Oct',10),('Nov',11),('Dec',12)])
```

However, this is returning month as Type int, size 1, value 1 and months as a list of size zero []. Not what I want!

This is where I write the bar chart stuffs:

```
output_file("stacked_bar.html")
bar = Bar(months, Companies, title="Number of Calls Each Month", palette = palette, legend = "top_right", width = 1200, height=900)
bar.add_tools(hover)


show(bar)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the index of `pivot_table` be an integer?

Comment: @ScottHunter It is CompanyName, which is a string.

Comment: In your first code fragment, you are using integers: `Jan = pivot_table[1]...`, but in the loop, you cast those integers to strings: `months.append(pivot_table[str(month)]...` Only one of those can work

Comment: @tobias_k a hah! I understand now. The problem is that when they were integers, I got this error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. It seems as though your answer below works if I take out the str in str(m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just mapping month names to numbers. Instead, you have to use the element of the `months`-list at that specific index. Also note that the indices in the list are still zero-based.

```
months_dict = OrderedDict([('Jan', months[0]), 
                           ('Feb', months[1]), 
                           ..., 
                           ('Dec', months[11])])
```

You could also make this a bit shorter by using a list-comprehension for the months and another list for the names and then just zipping those lists together, something like this:

```
months = [pivot_table[m].astype(float).values for m in range(1, 13)]
names = ["Jan", "Feb", ..., "Dec"]
months_dict = OrderedDict(list(zip(names, months)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the index of `pivot_table` be an integer?

Comment: @ScottHunter You are probably right... it's an integer in the first code, then a string in the second.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For the months_dict line, I don't have a list called values, did you mean months? Using this, I get a KeyError: '1' and m is an int of 1 in my variable explorer window.

Comment: @jenryb About `values`: Whops, my mistake, that should be `months`. About the key-error: It is not really clear from your question whether the indices in `pivot_table` should be `int` or `str`...

Comment: @tobias_k should be or are? To be honest I'm very confused about all the differences between types. The indeces are strings, CompanyName in the code. I put up my code for making the pivot_table, does this help?

Comment: This answer works if I take out 'str'! Thank you. But is there a different way to do it without the names? Like if I want to iterate over every hour instead, with 24 hours, I don't want to name them all.